# RestSharp - value without a name

Tags: c#, json, curl, jira, restsharp

I am trying to add a watcher to a Jira issue, using the REST API, C# and the RestSharp library.

According to [Jira's documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/6.1/#d2e1249), the name of the watcher to be added must be in the following format: "username" (just the value within double quotes, no name).

This is apparently not valid Json.

By following [this answer](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/61770/please-help-got-error-400-when-trying-to-add-watcher-using-rest-api), I was able to add a watcher to a Jira issue with Curl:

```
curl -i -u myusername:mypassword -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d "\"myusername\"" http://my.jira.host/rest/api/2/issue/MYISSUEKEY-1/watchers
```

However, It doesn't work with RestSharp (Jira answers bad request). Here's my code so far:

```
private RestRequest CreateRequest(Method method, String path)
{
    var request = new RestRequest { Method = method, Resource = path, RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json,  };
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format("{0}:{1}", username, password))));
    return request;
}

public void AddWatcher(string issueKey, string watcher)
{
    try
    {
        var path = String.Format("issue/{0}/watchers", issueKey);
        var request = CreateRequest(Method.POST, path);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.AddBody(string.Format("\"{0}\"", watcher));

        var response = client.Execute(request);
        AssertStatus(response, HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.TraceError("AddWatcher(issue, watcher) error: {0}", ex);
        throw new JiraClientException("Could not add watcher", ex);
    }
}
```

I would like to know if it's possible to send that type of POST via RestSharp, even if it's not a name / value pair.

Thanks